# Soda water first stored in refrigerator and then at room temperature

Tags: storage-method, food-science, storage

If I put an unopened bottle of soda water in the refrigerator and decide two weeks later that there is not enough room so I store it in a cabinet outside the refrigerator, will it lose its bubbly taste and carbon dioxide?

Answer (score 16):

If it's unopened it will stay perfectly fine, cold or warm, until the Best Before date printed on it.
It doesn't need refrigerating until opened - unless, of course, you want to drink it cold ;)

Answer (score 10):

The CO<sub>2</sub> would have to actually leave the bottle for the drink to go flat, and that's no more likely than when you store it at constant temperature. I often do this anyway as I'm short of fridge space and don't drink many fizzy drinks, and I've never had a problem

Comment: The storage temperature doesn't really matter, but the temperature when you open it matters a great deal.  If you open the bottle while it's warm, you'll lose more carbonation than if you open it while it's cold.